# Multiple plots in one figure in R: Error if only ONE column

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I'm trying to combine multiple figures into one using R / RStudio. It works fine when plotting 2 by 2, 3 by 5 etc. It works an all combinations with the exception of plotting ONE column. If I DO try to plot one column using [an example of the rather renomated help site statmethods.net](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html)

```
# 3 figures arranged in 3 rows and 1 column
attach(mtcars)
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
hist(wt)
hist(mpg)
hist(disp)
```

I get the message right after the second plot:

```
hist(mpg)

Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large
```

Has anybody experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RStudio will throw that error if the plot window is sized too small for what you are trying to plot.  You could try dragging that plot window larger relative to the console etc, or you could write your plot directly to a file, for instance using `pdf()` and `dev.off()`.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! I'm working on a 11" screen.. I would've never seen the physical window size as the source of the problem! Thanks a bunch for the quick answer!